# Is it possible to send twilio SMS text messages to landline phones (text-to-speech?)

Tags: twilio, sms-gateway

Outbound messages only - It appears that it can be done from a mobile phone by adding the 10-digit landline number to the SMS message.

Comment: i am not aware of any voice calls to landline numbers , btw text-speech will generate a audio file at mobile , but you cannot send the same to the landline

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

What you can do is take a text message that has been sent to a Twilio phone number, use our REST API to initiate an outbound phone call to the landline, then when the call is answered use out TTS engine to read the text message to the caller.

Some resources:

- [Receiving an incoming text message](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/sms/hello-monkey)
- [Making an outbound phone call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/rest/call-request)
- [TwiML `<Say>` Verb](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/say)

Hope that helps.